# Perl - API Post

Tags: perl

This is the first time I am trying to use Perl for Post API. Below is the code I have written.

```
use REST::Client;
use MIME::Base64;

my $username = 'user';
my $password = 'passwrd';

my $request_url =  'https:hereismyurl';
my $headers = {
   Authorization => 'Basic ' . encode_base64($username . ':' . $password),
   OSvC-CREST-Application-Context => 'Test',
   Content-type => 'application/json'
};    
my $body_content='{"id" :106197,"filters":[{"name": "Date Range","values":["2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z","2021-09-28T00:00:00.000Z"]}]}';    
my $client = REST::Client->new();
$client->POST($request_url, [$body_content, %$headers]);
print $client->responseContent();
```

But I get the below error.

> Not a SCALAR reference at /usr/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 203.

Please can someone help me as to where I’m going wrong, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You should do

```
$client->POST($request_url, $body_content, $headers);
```

instead of

```
$client->POST($request_url, [$body_content, %$headers]);
```

The `[$body_content, %$headers]` in the documation mean that those 2 parameters are optional, and that `$headers` should be a hash reference.

Moreover, you should quote `OSvC-CREST-Application-Context` and `Content-type`:

```
my $headers = {
   Authorization => 'Basic ' . encode_base64($username . ':' . $password),
   'OSvC-CREST-Application-Context' => 'Test',
   'Content-type' => 'application/json'
};
```

Otherwise, Perl thinks that `Content` and `type` are two strings representing numbers that you are trying to subtract, and interprets them as `0` and `0`. You thus get `0 => 'Test', 0 => 'application/json'` in your hash (and only the latter remains).
To catch this kind of mistakes, always add `use strict` and `use warnings` at the beginning of your scripts. Here, this would have produced the following errors:

> Bareword "OSvC" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at t3.pl line 11.
> Bareword "CREST" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at t3.pl line 11.
> Bareword "Application" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at t3.pl line 11.
> Bareword "Content" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at t3.pl line 11.